# python replace content of url between <br/> and <br/>

Tags: python, python-3.x

There's a string like this:

```
<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/>https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0<br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>
```

I want to delete the content:

```
https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0
```

Just keep:

```
<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/><br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>
```

My code:

```
mystring = '<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/>https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0<br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>'
```

How to do it?

Comment: Try `BeautifulSoup`. Also, what's special about `https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0`? Are you looking to strip all the URLs inside a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` from regex module:

```
import re
mystring = '<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/>https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0<br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>'
print(re.sub(r'http[^<]+', '', mystring))
```

Output:

```
<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/><br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regex replace:

Find: `<br/>https?://[^<]*</br>`

Replace: `<br/></br>`

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = '<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/>https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0<br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>'
# remove 'https://sites.google.com/aaa-net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0'
resultstring = '<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/><br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>'

length = len(mystring)
startPos = -1
endPos = -1
for i in range(length):
    subString = mystring[i:]
    if subString.startswith('<br/>'):
        if(startPos == -1):
            startPos = i
            continue # check from next character to get endPos

        if(endPos == -1):
            endPos = i


firstSubString = mystring[:startPos + 5] # 5 = the characher size of '<br/>'
lastSubString = mystring[endPos:]


completeResult = firstSubString + lastSubString
print(completeResult, completeResult == resultstring)
print(completeResult, resultstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

mystring = '<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/>https://sites.google.com/aaa- 
net.bb.cc/be-do-have/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0<br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>'
print(re.sub("(?:<br/>https)([\s\S]*?)(?=<br/>)",'<br/>',mystring))
```

Output:

```
<p>Millions of people watch TV.</p><br/><br/><p>Good boy!</p><br/>
```